# Trusted and scalable embedded database

Tags: database, embedded-database

I'm looking for a DB embedded solution to deal with a average/medium amount of data (maybe between 100MB to 2GB), and allow concurrent connections, not so much, I believe at least
more than 10 concurrent connections for objects (database, tables) up to fifty or one hundred.

Which options could be achieve these requirements in your opinion and experience?

Comment: For which programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java you have a choice of three different DBMS:

- HSQLDB (aka HyperSQL): http://hsqldb.org
- H2 Database: http://h2database.com/html/main.html
- Apache Derby (aka. "JavaDB"): http://db.apache.org/derby/

My personal preference is HSQLDB, but H2 is just as good. Both meet the requirements you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) can be used embedded. It meets all your other requirements.